# Change timezone info for multiple datetime columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Is there a easy way of converting all timestamp columns in a dataframe to local/any  timezone?

Not by doing it column by column?

Comment: select all timestamp columns with select_dtypes, then apply tz_localize to each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can selectively apply the conversion to all datetime columns. First, select them with [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html#pandas-dataframe-select-dtypes), then call [`tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html) inside `apply`:

```
df2 = df.select_dtypes('datetimetz')
df[df2.columns] = df2.apply(lambda x: x.dt.tz_convert(None))
```

"datetimetz" selects all datetime columns with timezone information.
Replace `tz_convert(None)` with `tz_convert(your_timezone)` to convert to a different timezone.

For plain datetime objects without any timezone info, call [`tz_localize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) first with your current timezone before calling `tz_convert`.

Comment: I think you should include the statement from your comment - for naive datetime objects, one would have to `tz_localize` first before calling `tz_convert` to change the timezone.

Comment: Nice, python and pandas always amazes me again. Just correct `select_dtypes`. One more question: my time coloumns where ISO (`'2020-06-01T22:00:00Z'`), so I had to convert them one by one. Is there a short way too?

Comment: @nanuuq Could you explain what you meant by having to convert them "one by one"? If you meant to say you have a column of strings instead of datetimes you could always use `pd.to_datetime` to convert it.

Comment: @cs95 opened a new question about that https://stackoverflow.com/q/62117425/3157070?sem=2

Comment: @nanuuq I endorse the answer you received on that question - df.apply is the defacto way to broadcast a per-column operation across multiple columns if an inbuilt function for it doesn't already exist...

Comment: @cs95 yes, learned a lot from both questions. In your example code, there is the d in `select_types`missing. Tried to edit it but couldn't. Thanks again

Comment: @nanuuq appreciate the nit, fixed