# Pandas multiple ISO time columns to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have multiple columns with ISO data strings like

`"CreateDate": "2020-04-30T06:12:29.424Z", "ApprovedDate": "2020-04-30T06:21:30.504Z"`

When I use column by column with

`df['CreateDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CreateDate'], infer_datetime_format=True, utc=True)`

it works fine. But

`df[['CreateDate', 'ApprovedDate']] = pd.to_datetime(df[['CreateDate', 'ApprovedDate']], infer_datetime_format=True, utc=True)`

gives me

`ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing`

Any ideas how to solve that? Tried all to_datetime options, but no succes.

Comment: According to the documentation, `pd.Datetime` expects a **Series** or **DataFrame/dict-like**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have nice ISO format strings, you should not be required to call `to_datetime` with any keywords. Therefore, a simple `apply` should be an option:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"CreateDate": ["2020-04-30T06:12:29.424Z"], 
                   "ApprovedDate": ["2020-04-30T06:21:30.504Z"]})

df[['CreateDate', 'ApprovedDate']] = df[['CreateDate', 'ApprovedDate']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
# df
#                         CreateDate                     ApprovedDate
# 0 2020-04-30 06:12:29.424000+00:00 2020-04-30 06:21:30.504000+00:00
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine. This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/62090561/3157070,

Comment: @nanuuq: right, cs95 was faster to give an answer on that one ;-) Anyways, since you seem to have tz set already (UTC), you can directly use `tz_convert`.